# Android fails to reconnect to different wireless access point

Tags: android, wireless

I have a very large (spatially) corporate wireless network that my fleet of Android phones need to operate in. As mentioned in [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335192/quick-notification-silence) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238997/android-long-duration-socket-listener), they will run a custom app that makes them behave like pagers, which works by keeping a long-duration socket open, listening for messages from a server.

My problem is that sometimes the devices do not handle the transition from access point A to access point B smoothly. I am basing this on the following log snippet which I was able to capture from one of the phones exhibiting this problem.

```
06-27 14:00:29.573: INFO/wpa_supplicant(1443): Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
06-27 14:00:29.573: INFO/wpa_supplicant(1443): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=7
06-27 14:00:29.573: INFO/wpa_supplicant(1443): CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:00:00:00:00:00 completed (reauth) [id=1 id_str=]
06-27 14:00:29.573: INFO/wpa_supplicant(1443): CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiStateTracker(1356): Changing supplicant state: COMPLETED ==> ASSOCIATED
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00]
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=7]
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:00:00:00:00:00 completed (reauth) [id=1 id_str=]]
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=4]
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00]
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=1 state=7]
06-27 14:00:29.573: VERBOSE/WifiMonitor(1356): Event [CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:00:00:00:00:00 completed (reauth) [id=1 id_str=]]
```

Can anyone help me understand why my router's BSSID is showing up as `00:00:00:00:00:00`? I am not a network expert, but that seems clearly wrong.

Perhaps I am misusing the Android API, but the snippet above seems to deal with a layer that is far beneath my application. I have read that some access points do not work correctly with the Android low power mode; could this be what I am seeing?

Thanks sincerely for any input.

Edit:
Here is the output from `dumpsys wifi`

```
Wi-Fi is enabled
Stay-awake conditions: 0

Internal state:
interface wlan0 runState=Running
SSID: rfVCRMC, BSSID: 00:00:00:00:00:00, MAC: 5C:DA:D4:12:46:2B, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, RSSI: -200, Link speed: 2, Net ID: 1
ipaddr 10.192.2.70 gateway 10.192.7.254 netmask 255.255.248.0 dns1 10.1.2.253 dns2 10.1.2.227 DHCP server 10.1.2.253 lease 14400 seconds
haveIpAddress=true, obtainingIpAddress=false, scanModeActive=false
lastSignalLevel=-1, explicitlyDisabled=false

Latest scan results:
  BSSID              Frequency   RSSI  Flags             SSID
  00:0c:41:dd:f5:b2       2437    -93  [WPA2-PSK-CCMP]   idcwap
  00:1b:d5:16:99:b0       2442    -93  [WEP]             rfVCRMC
  00:0f:24:c3:6f:d0       2437    -90                    Guest
  00:1b:d5:16:99:b0       2442    -93                    Guest

Locks acquired: 4 full, 0 scan
Locks released: 3 full, 0 scan

Locks held:
    WifiLock{VCD_ListenerService type=1 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@44cbd5b8}
```

Comment: What make/model are the devices? Are all the devices the exact same make and model?

Comment: The model is the LG Ally, running 2.2.1. All exactly the same.

Comment: Hey did you find out why is it showing 00:00:00:00:00:00? @WorkerThread

Comment: @WorkerThread Hey I have been searching for getting these communication between mobile(Android) and AP. How did u get this log data? Plz help me out